# Get the next row of a dataframe in R programming

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I am working on an **R** programming project..

I have a dataframe (df) with about 790 observations in. I am trying to extract certain rows from the dataframe. The only similarity with the row I am trying to extract with the row above, which are all named S_NAME:

1 cat

2 hat

3 S_NAME

4 tin

5 sin

6 S_NAME

7 foo

8 sin

9 S_NAME

10 tinn

So for example, I would want to extract row 4,7 and 10 which all follow S_NAME

I am unsure of how to do this, any help will be great thanks. I know I have tagged python, although that code might help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
ktore <- which(df[, 2]=="S_NAME")    # check in which row there is S_NAME
df[ktore+1, ]   # extract rows which are after them

4   4  tin
7   7  foo
10 10 tinn
```

Comment: Hi, how would i get all rows inbetween s_name please? thanks @marta

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=c("cat", "hat", "S_NAME", "fred", "joe", "S_NAME", "bob", "jeff", "S_NAME", "final"))
print(df)
df[which(df$b == "S_NAME")+1, ]

# to extract rows inbetween rows containing S_NAME:
S_NAME.inds <- which(df$b == "S_NAME")
rows <- 1:nrow(df)
df[df$b != "S_NAME" & rows > S_NAME.inds[1] & rows < S_NAME.inds[S_NAME.nums], ]
```

Comment: How would i go about getting all rows inbetween S_NAME please. thanks

Comment: Do you mean rows that aren't S_NAME, or rows inbetween S_NAME (ie. excluding rows before the first S_NAME and after the last S_NAME)?

Comment: yes rows between the first S_NAME and the second S_NAME then between the second S_NAME and third S_NAME. Thanks

Comment: Off the top of my head, combining some logicals does that job.